# Fill a jcombobox with the all tables from a data base

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to populate a JComboBox with the tables in a database, I have this code that executes the query and the result sent him to another class in which I fill the JComboBox with data fix, the problem is that I receive only garbage.

The code of the query and connection

```
public ArrayList Tablas()
{    
    ArrayList tabla = new ArrayList(); 
    int i=0;
    try 
    {
        this.conectar("127.0.0.1", "mydb", "root", "root");
        this.consulta=this.conn.prepareStatement("show tables;");
        this.datos=this.consulta.executeQuery();
        while(datos.next())
        {
            tabla.add(datos);
            i++;
        }
        return tabla;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Servicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return tabla;
    }
}
```

appreciate your help

And the part where I'm trying to set the Jcombobox

```
    Servicio service = new Servicio();  
    ArrayList<String> tabla = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    tabla = service.Tablas();
    DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(tabla.toArray());
    cTablas.setModel(model);
```

Comment: "the problem is that I receive only garbage" - how is that gonna tell us what the problem is?

Comment: Hi, sorry not be more specific, i already resolve the problem, i add tabla.add(datos.getString(1)); to the code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 ArrayList tabla = new ArrayList();
```

Change this to

```
List<String> tabla = new ArrayList();
```

Change

```
while(datos.next())
        {
            tabla.add(datos);
            i++;
        }
```

To

```
while(datos.next())
        {
            tabla.add(datos.get...(i);
            i++;
        }
```

Let us know what is the error you are getting. Alongwith the stacktrace if any.
P.S - I have just typed the codes in text editor just to give you an idea. So change pieces if needed.

Comment: Hi Hirak, thank you for the answer, I already resolve my problem, just add "tabla.add(datos.getString(1));" and now works, sorry for the inconvenient about my post and my poor description of the problem, I expect improve, regards

Comment: No problem.... if you see my answer, I suggested the same 
" tabla.add(datos.get...(i);"

Comment: Yes, it is funny because I was working on this like 2 hours and the answer it's so simple